# Возможно ли получить дату изменения google таблицы не используя API google?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли получить дату изменения таблицы google используя только библиотеку `requests`? Т.е получить информацию о файле из URL parameters?
Например, по такому же принципу, как я экспортирую файл в .csv:

```
with open('Example.csv', 'w') as f:

    docUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nDLXuQ7YyRbpz9owL_sLeQ/export?format=csv'

    docContent = requests.get(docUrl)

    f.write(docContent.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что приходит в `docContent.headers`, может там есть что-то полезное. Я не могу посмотреть ваш файл, мне приходит ответ `404`, видимо, у меня нет прав доступа к этому файлу. )

Comment: Сссылка на файл просто для примера, это может быть любая таблица

Comment: Ну надо на рабочей ссылке проверить. Может в `headers` выдаёт какую-то полезную дату. А может и не выдаёт, в этом случае не знаю, где ещё поискать можно.

Comment: Проверил на рабочей ссылке из ответа, не нашёл там полезных дат (

Comment: Да, там только текущая дата.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из решений что пришло на ум. Я думаю что это лучше, чем через какое-то время грузить снова всю таблицу целиком.

Можно следить за ее обновлением так:

В гугл таблицах есть функция `=ТДАТА()` , которая возвращает дату последнего изменения в таблице. Но, как я понял экспортировать отдельно содержимое ячейки нельзя, используя заголовок типа:`export?range=А1:A2`, экспортируется вся таблица. Это доступно только для `view?` Также нельзя экспортировать лист отдельно `export?gid=0`

Нужно создать отдельную таблицу и следить за обновлением других используя функцию `=IMPORTRANGE()` для того, чтобы импортировать значения даты изменения из других таблиц.

Например, эта таблица: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dZcKffBFGDY7Mp5aBzq_Bgt1DP4fUcrVVf7b-YvRGDo/edit#gid=0

Соответственно с помощью `requests.get(URL)` можно следить только за этими значениями. И при необходимости обновлять файл основной таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('libs/credentials/credentials.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
work_table = client.open('WorkList')
print(work_table.lastUpdateTime)
```

'''

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]